# Modify registration URL

Tags: php, wordpress

This code displays a 'Register' link; I want to redirect this link to "www.myDomain.com/register/" how can I change this?

```
<?php
  if ( get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) :
  $registration_url = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( wp_registration_url() ), __( 'Register' ) );``/*** Filter the registration URL below the login form.
  ** @since 1.5.2** @param string $registration_url Registration URL.
  */echo ' | ' . apply_filters( 'register', $registration_url );endif;?></p>
```

Comment: I changed this:

$registration_url = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( wp_registration_url() ), __( 'Register' ) );

To:
$registration_url = sprintf( '<a href="http://www.myDomain.com/register">Register</a>', esc_url( wp_registration_url() ), __( 'Register' ) );

and its working now.

Comment: This way you have to edit every template with a registration link, and core/theme changes will be overwritten on update. I added a code sample to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use the register_url [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) to modify the URL returned by [wp_registration_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_registration_url).

**Sample code** (put it in your plugin or theme/functions.php file):

```
add_filter( 'register_url', 'custom_register_url' );
function custom_register_url( $register_url )
{
    $register_url = "YOUR_PAGE_URL";
    return $register_url;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly what to modify, em not a coder sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<?php
if ( get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) :
    echo ' | ' . apply_filters( 'register', 'http://www.myDomain.com/register/' );
endif;
?>
```

Not very elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Careful with this one, you have to do this everywhere or you'll end up with different links on different pages.

Answer (score -2):

I think you would have to edit the general-template.php.  The function would be

```
function wp_registration_url() {
        return apply_filters( 'register_url', site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login' ) );
```

if you changed it to

```
function wp_registration_url() {
        return apply_filters( 'register_url', 'http://www.mydoamin.com/register'));
```

it should change it where ever that wp_registration_url is referenced.

Comment: It will break on updating WordPress. Adding a filter to your theme is easier than editing core files, and it's future-proof.